# LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE ampersand issue

Tags: mysql, xml

I want to import XML data which contains ampersands into MySQL.

The import fails to run after a row has been encountered with a raw ampersand (&). Admittedly this is not correct XML but that is what I am working with.

I have tried replacing the raw ampersands with `&#038;` - this appears in the database as the raw text (not the equivalent ASCII ampersand).

I have tried replacing the raw ampersands with `\&` - this stops the import routine from running further.

Can you suggest how I can get the raw ampersand into the database using `LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE`?

Sample raw XML follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<REPORT>
    <CLA>
        <PLOT>R&S</PLOT>
        <VAL>100.10</VAL>
    </CLA>
    <CLA>
        <PLOT>G&N</PLOT>
        <VAL>200.20</VAL>
    </CLA>
</REPORT>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Admittedly this is not correct xml but that is what I am working
>   with.

No, it's not that it's *incorrect XML*.   It is ***not XML at all*** because it is not [*well-formed*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25830482/290085).

You have two ways forward:

1. Fix the data by treating it as text to turn it into XML.  (Replace
   the `&` with `&amp;`.)
2. Load the data into the database using a non-XML data type.

Comment: Thanks, replaced by `&amp;`